# Uncaught Error: Make sure that slide 0 has an image/video src lightgallery

Tags: javascript, angularjs, video.js, lightgallery

I am facing issue with light gallery with video js in angular js .
**Uncaught Error: Make sure that slide 0 has an image/video src**

```
<ul class="gallerybox gallery"  id ="video-gallery">
        <li ng-repeat="image in gallery" data-poster="{{image.thumbnail}}" data-sub-html="video caption2" data-html="#video{{index}}" id="{{image.id}}">
        <img ng-src="{{image.thumbnail}}" />
        </li>
    </ul>
     <div style="display:none;" id="video{{$index}}"  ng-repeat="image in gallery" >
        <video width="320" height="240" controls>
            <source src="http://example.com/8/video/59cbcf659fee7.mp4-export-webm.webm"  type="video/webm">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
I commented/removed this line from lightgallery.js :

```
if (!src) {
        throw new Error("Make sure that slide " + index + " has an image/video src");
    }
```

Now everything works well !